# UITableView looks right in simulator and wrong in actual device - iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which loads fine in the simulator and all devices other than iPhone 4s. I have been searching for answers for a while and even put this on hold until now hoping that I would think of a solution but nothing seems to work.

The solution I tried was to remove possible conflicting code which is now commented like below.

```
// Remove seperator inset
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    //[cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}

// Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
    //[cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
}

// Explictly set your cell's layout margins
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    //[cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

My current code looks like this

```
- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 4;
}

-(double) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 3) {
        return 700.0;
    }
    return 44.0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 3) {
        static NSString *homeTableIdentifier = @"GeneralInfoTableViewCell";

        GeneralInfoTableViewCell *cell = (GeneralInfoTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:homeTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GeneralInfoTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell;
    } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
...
```

Please note that I edited out the logo which shows up twice in this view which is why "erbjudanden" is cut off in the wrong view below.

This is what the view looks like in the iPhone 4s simulator (correct way).

[image]

This is what the view looks like on the actual iPhone 4s (wrong way)

[image]

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: I think it's cell's height issue. You need to increase height

Comment: what is your ios version of your device and simulator?

Comment: @Misha can you explain how this would help and if I should increase the height of the cell or the number being returned in heightForRowAtIndexPath? all cells are 44 in height except one which is 700. These are custom and very basic tableviewcells which have a height defined to 44 with the exception of one which is 700. Thanks!

Comment: @EICaptain device is 8.1 and simulator shows the same 8.1, 8.2 and 8.4. Screenshot of simulator is from 8.4.

Comment: I think you have set backgroundColor of Cell and contentView to UIColor ClearColor that's why text is showing below the sepeartor otherwise it would be trucated.

Comment: @Misha hmm, maybe I need to improve my question. The cells should all be large enough to fit the text, this is not my problem. The problem is that the content inside the cells are out of place only on the iPhone 4s device. As you may be able to see a lot of content gets pushed up and none of the cells get set to a height of 700 on iPhone 4s. This works fine on all simulators and all of our devices with the exception of iPhone 4s.

Comment: maybe you need to use expectedHeight ?

Comment: @EICaptain I posted my code for heightForRowAtIndexPath above if that is what you are asking? My custom cells have height defined in the xib file.

Comment: I recreated the entire view and now it works. I am not really sure what I did differently but it seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues here as my device was running iOS 10, whereas my simulator was running iOS 9.3.

I suspect that the view hierarchy calls happen in a slightly different order, resulting in the difference of display between the two.

A call to `view.layoutIfNeeded()` just before updating the required views helped me out.